# PHP Parse Error unexpected {, expecting ( - don't understand why

Tags: php

I know it might be a really dumb question but I really was not able to make it work. I am trying to do a webservice with PHP. I get some a PHP Parse Error but can't figure out why.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' in /www/htdocs/flight/webserv/shiftswop_register_group.php on line 25
```

And here is a part of my code of the Class:

```
<?php


include 'shiftswop_constants.php';
include 'shiftswop_db_connect.php';



class shiftSwitchRegisterGroupAPI {

private $db;

//constructor
function __construct() {
    $this -> db = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    $this -> db -> autocommit(FALSE);
}

//decstructor

function __destruct(){
    $this -> db -> close();
}

function create {      <======== THIS IS LINE 25

    if(isset($_POST[KEY_GROUP_NAME]) && isset($_POST[KEY_GROUP_PASSWORD]) && isset($_POST[KEY_USER_ID]) && isset($_POST[KEY_USER_PASSWORD])){

        $groupName = $_POST[KEY_GROUP_NAME];
        $groupPassword = $_POST[KEY_GROUP_PASSWORD];
        $userId = $_POST[KEY_USER_ID];
        $userPassword = $_POST[KEY_USER_PASSWORD];



        $groupName = str_replace(" ", "_", $groupName);
```

This is whats in the connect.php file:

```
<?php

define("HOST", "www.*****.de");
define("USER", "f****r");
define("PASSWORD", "*****");
define("DATABASE", "f********er");
?>
```

And this is the contstants File:

```
<?php
define("KEY_USER_ID", "userId");
define("KEY_USER_FIRST_NAME", "userFirstName");
define("KEY_USER_LAST_NAME", "userLastName");
define("KEY_USER_INITIALS", "userInitials");
define("KEY_USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS", "userEmailAddress");
define("KEY_USER_TELEFON_NUMBER", "userTelefonNumber");
define("KEY_USER_PASSWORD", "userPassword");
define("KEY_USER_LAST_SUCCESSFUL_SYNC", "userLastSuccessfulSync");  
define("KEY_GROUP_ID", "groupId");
define("KEY_GROUP_NAME", "groupName");
define("KEY_GROUP_PASSWORD", "groupPassword");

?>
```

And so on.... I do not understand why it is expecting a "("

Can please anybody have a look?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis `()` -> `function create()`

Comment: Why don't you read the error message? Unexpected `{`, expecting `(` ... So you need `function create() {` syntax, instead of `function create {`

Comment: your create function doesn't have the function () braces after function name.
just add () after function name...

Comment: thank you all you are really quick!!! => i am just tooo blind!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this works. You need to change:

```
function create {
```

to

```
function create() {
```

Comment: Don't hope, it will work, am sure :)

Comment: Good point Mr. Alien. See this questions for why PHP needs the empty parentheses (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833502/why-does-a-php-function-with-no-parameters-require-parentheses)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add parenthesis before the curly braces:

```
function create() {

}
```